# Letting Another to Sign an APK with My Private-Key - How?

Tags: android, apk, keystore, android-keystore

To enable another developer to sign an APK with one of my private-keys, should I give out the original KeyStore file, or would giving him only this specific key's password be enough?

*Please note* that my question intentionally disregards the "security" aspects of giving out a private signing key. This is not part of the question.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the other developer with the following:

- The Keystore file
- The password to the keystore
- The name of the alias used to sign the app
- The password to that alias.

If you wish, you can export the certificate for a single alias to a different keystore using the following commands:

```
keytool -export -alias myAlias -file mycert.cer -keystore existingKeystore.jks
keytool -importcert -file mycert.cer -keystore newKeystore.jks -alias myAlias
```

This is useful if you have multiple certificates in a single keystore and you only want to export a single certificate.

Comment: First - Thanks much. Second: If I export the only key of interest to a separate KeyStore, would he be able to sign the APK with that key in such a manner that Google Play-Store would recognize this APK as the same app, i.e. as a successor of the last published revision?

Comment: Yes. A keystore is just a collection of certificates, and the Play Store requires that your app's certificate has the same signature each time you upload. As long as you sign your app with the same certificate each time, it doesn't matter which keystore file it came from.

Comment: Thanks much again. The reason I've asked this last continuation-question: After I've created my KeyStore, I've renamed the file. On the next time I've tried to use this KeyStore to sign my app, Eclipse has claimed that the "KeyStore file has been tampered with". I've changed nothing in its content, but rather only file's name. This made be suspect that the KeyStore somehow keeps track of information about the file containing it, and hence - to let someone sign an APK with one of my keys, I would have to give out the ORIGINAL KeyStore file.

Comment: That sounds like a problem unrelated to the renaming. If all you did was change the file name, you should be fine. It is possible that Eclipse simply cannot locate the keystore, or you need to double check the alias and password information.

Comment: Either way, thanks. Your assistance is much obliged.

Comment: I've tried exporting the single key to a separate KeyStore. Opreration succeeded, but coming to use this new KeyStore to sign the app, Eclipse says: "Invalid keystore format".

Comment: My apologies, the export only exports the cert, which you then need to import into the new keystore. I've updated my instructions for doing so.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. So basically, I could just give him the *mycert.cer* file and key's password, and he could form a KeyStore for himself, using the second *keytool* command you suggested. Is this correct?

Comment: Well, now, indeed - I have a new KeyStore (with a different password), containing the original key. I can successfully open the KeyStore using Eclipse. It properly shows the key I have added to it (the correct alias). I enter key's password, and it is accepted, but then, When I press *Next*, nothing happens. It does not continue to the dialog asking for output APK file's path, nor does it show any error. It just does not respond. Are you familiar with that?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I'm not. You could try [signing manually](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#signing-manually) to determine whether it is an Eclipse issue or an issue with the key.

Comment: guys i'm sorry to bother, I have a similar kind of matter if you can check this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64957655/android-app-generate-a-keystore-from-private-key