# generate a keystore from private key

Tags: android, android-studio, keystore, android-keystore

I lost my keystore after updating Android Studio (I searched everywhere on my machine.)

Now I want to avoid losing days making a request for a new Key to Google's support.

I found that I still have the initial private_key.pepk, and distribution/upload certificates (.der) as well as the keystore passwords and Alias.

Is it possible to regenerate a valid keystore from these information, to sign an APK?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Android Studio? If so, then you should be able to generate a new keystore from there automatically. I believe this won't affect your previous apps if you use a new keystore.

Comment: Unfortunately it does affect my previous app since it was published, and i can't regenerate from an existing key using Android studio